# why can't push static const member into vector?

Tags: c++

why can't push static const member into vector?

static const, static const constexpr, can't push into
static, non-static, and static const outside class, can push
**sorry. I missed scope specifier , well I mean the situation that added specifier, can’t push static const member**

```
struct A {
    static const constexpr int sccv = 0;
    static const int scv = 0;
    static int sv = 0;
    const int cv = 0;
};

int main () {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(A::sccv);            // error
    vec.push_back(A::scv);             // error
    vec.push_back(A::sv);              // pass
    vec.push_back((new A())->cv);   // pass
    static const int sc = 0;
    vec.push_back(sc);              // pass
}
```

Comment: You missed to specify the `A::` scope dude!

Comment: I don't believe that `vec.push_back(sv);` pass.

Comment: most of us are not native speakers, but you could at least try to write complete sentences

Comment: Is the error message a secret?

Comment: Possible can be duplicated to https://stackoverflow.com/q/4891067/5698157

Comment: Yep that's a good dupe thanks. Have started the reopen process so it can be closed as dupe

Answer (score 2):

First I will assume that you wrote `A::` at point-of-use, otherwise none of this code would have compiled.

When you "use" an object that has namespace-scope or is a class member, that is declared `static`, you must generally have a *definition* for it somewhere.

It might seem weird that a definition is needed even though you provided an initialiser at the point of declaration. That's because providing an initial value is only a small part of what a definition does. The more important part is giving the object a home, somewhere to live, specifying which compiled "module" will host the memory required for the object's existence. Like any object, your static member needs to be instantiated somewhere; the fact that it is lexically declared inside a class definition is a bit of a red herring.

So:

```
struct A {
    static const constexpr int sccv = 0;
    static const int scv = 0;
    static int sv = 0;
    const int cv = 0;
};

// In precisely one source file:
const constexpr int A::sccv;
const int A::scv;
int A::sv;
```

Now you won't get that "undefined reference" linker error any more.

There are some exceptions to the rule, and there are some scenarios in which compiler optimisations result in your program appearing to work regardless.

Comment: Thanks, it’s weird that definition is still needed if already given initial value in declaration

Comment: @mewo1234: It's because providing an initial value is only a small part of what a definition does. The more important part is giving the object a home, somewhere to live, specifying which compiled "module" will host the memory required for the object's existence. Like any object, your `static` member needs to be instantiated somewhere; the fact that it is lexically declared inside a class definition is a bit of a red herring.