# Syntax error when initializing a static variable

Tags: c++, static, constructor, compiler-errors

There are two classes defined..

```
    class Dictionary
    {
    public:
        Dictionary();
        Dictionary(int i);
// ...
    };
```

and

```
    class Equation
    {
        static Dictionary operator_list(1);
// ...

    };
```

but the problem is, whenever I compile this, I get a weird error message

> error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'

But it compiles well when I use the default constructor on operator_list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ you cannot combine declaration and initialization. When you do not specify constructor parameters of `operator_list`, you do not call its default constructor: you simply declare it. You need to also initialize it in the corresponding C++ file, like this:

Equation.h

```
class Equation {
    static Dictionary operator_list;
};
```

Equation.cpp:

```
Dictionary Equation::operator_list(1);
```

Note the absence of `static` in the CPP file: it is not there by design. The compiler already knows from the declaration that `operator_list` is static.

Edit: You have a choice with static constant members of integral and enumerated types: you can initialize them in the CPP file as in the example above, or you can give them a value in the header. You still need to define that member in your C++ file, but you must not give it a value at the definition time.

Comment: **"In C++ you cannot combine declaration and initialization."** What exactly do you mean by this statement ?

Comment: In fact, you can if you are doing it with an int : `If a static data member is of const integral or const enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a constant-initializer which shall be an integral constant expression`

Comment: @Drahakar Here is [my reference](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.11). Perhaps it's outdated, but that's exactly what I've learned some 15 years ago, and continue to use to this day.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Drahakar refers to the C++ standard so, that's by definition more valid than your reference :). If equation was an int the OP's code would be valid.

Comment: The reference discusses static int. Static const int members *can* be initialized at declaration time, but a non-const static int member *cannot*.

Comment: @FailedDev I guess I'm dating myself here, but I learned that trick before the first C++ ISO standard has been approved. I updated the answer to mention the alternative available for constant integral/enum types. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`static Dictionary operator_list();` is a function signature declaring a function returning a `Dictionary` and taking no arguments, that's why your compiler let you do it.

The reasons `static Dictionary operator_list(1);` fails is because you can't set a value of an complex type in the declaration of your classes. You need to do this elsewhere (e.g. in the .cpp )

For more information, see this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3792427/103916

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Dictionary
{
public:
    Dictionary() {}
    Dictionary(int i):page(i) {}
    void display() { cout << "page is " << page << endl; }
private:
    int page;
};

class Equation
{
    public:
    static Dictionary operator_list;

};

Dictionary Equation::operator_list(1); // static members must be initialized this way...

int main()
{
Equation::operator_list.display();
}
```

Output is:

```
page is 1
```