# How do I initialize this static class variable in my template class?

Tags: c++, c++03

I have the following code ([it's on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/WGqn8w)):

```
template<class T>
class CMemoryPool
{
public:
    CMemoryPool(int param1)
        : stuff(param1)
    {}

private:
    T stuff;
};

template<class T>
class CList
{
public:
    struct Entry
    {
        T data;
    };

    static CMemoryPool<Entry> s_pool;
};

template<class T>
CList<T>::CMemoryPool<CList<T>::Entry>::s_pool(1);

int main()
{
    CList<int> list;
}
```

I can't seem to get the initialization of `s_pool` outside of the class to compile. Can anyone help me figure out how to make this work? Note I'm using C++03 only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members

Comment: This has been asked many times:

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185844/initializing-private-static-members
 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461546/c-initializing-static-variable

Comment: **this is for a template class, your links to the simple scenarios do not answer my question**

Comment: Just use the Template type of T

Comment: Pretty sure you need a `typename` for `CList<T>::Entry`, but unfortunately [this also didn't fix it](http://ideone.com/RpysDz) :( ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: 
I was under the impression that:

> You must explicitly give value to the static value for each instantiation of the template:
>
> ```
> CList<int>::CMemoryPool<CList<int>::Entry>::s_pool(1);
> ```
>
> must be somewhere in your *.C files...
>
> Alternatively, use a static local variable in a method of the table used to get the value.

But after playing a bit, this seems to compile in ideone

```
template<class T>
CMemoryPool<typename CList<T>::Entry> CList<T>::s_pool(1);
```

I still recommend @FredOverflow solution as it protects your from [static initialization problems](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html)

Comment: Most other template statics can be initialized with type `T`, so why do I need to do it explicitly for each type in this case?

Comment: Ah I feel stupid now! The static initialization statement was missing its type! Great job!

Comment: @RobertDailey ... still... I'm not sure how this would play when this template is properly defined on its *.h file and included in multiple places... anyone knows?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you forgot how initializing a static data member works in general:

```
struct Data { int i; };

struct Holder { static Data StaticMember; };

Data Holder::StaticMember = { 1 };
^    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ static member qualified name
\~~~ static member type
```

If you look at your declaration, it is striking that you forgot one of the two above:

```
// Only a single element: there should be a type and a name
template<class T>
CList<T>::template CMemoryPool<typename CList<T>::Entry>::s_pool(1);

// Two elements
template<class T>
CMemoryPool<typename CList<T>::Entry> CList<T>::s_pool(1);
^                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ name
 \~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ type
```

Once corrected [it just works](http://ideone.com/3VNDBy)

Comment: The code itself is fairly obfuscated so I missed an basic and fundamental piece.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem with the spaces popping within types: it looks right, but in fact isn't. What clued me in is that in your declaration somehow `CMemoryPool` ended up as a nested type inside `CList` which seemed fishy and I had to step back to realize what was truly happening.

Answer (score 1):

Static data members inside class templates are somewhat of a pain to initialize. I suggest a factory function instead. Then you don't need to worry about defining the variable somewhere else.

Just rewrite the line

```
static CMemoryPool<Entry> s_pool;
```

to

```
static CMemoryPool<Entry>& s_pool()
{
    static CMemoryPool<Entry> foobar;
    return foobar;
}
```

And then use `s_pool()` instead `s_pool` everywhere. You get lazy initialization as a benefit.

Comment: Doesn't answer my question

Comment: @FredOverflow probably you're missing `static CMemoryPool<Entry> foobar(1);` that would replace the original `CList<T>::CMemoryPool<CList<T>::Entry>::s_pool(1);`

Comment: @RobertDailey I've been playing around with your code a bit, and couldn't get it syntactically right. I'd say Freds answer well answers your question, or let's better say: solves your problem elegantly.

Comment: I'm not looking for an elegant solution, this is an experiment for me (learning exercise). I found this problem and can't solve it, would be nice to see the solution. I understand there are alternative ways to do the same thing, but that's not what I'm asking for.